# Vimeo video won't play in Safari on some networks

Tags: iframe, vimeo

Strange problem with Vimeo, embed Vimeo video is playing normal on chrome, safari, mozzila,  explorer, when page loads video auto play. But when i connect to different wifi there is problem with Safari, Vimeo shows just for one second and disappears. All browsers works ok except Safari. The biggest problem is that 5 people checked it, and 3 people see the video normally in Safari, and 2 have this problem (again, all other browsers works ok)

Someone had this problem?

After cache clear, checking embed code, changing iframe parameters, problem still exists. Video does not have any restrictions, it is public